# how to forward requests to another microservice using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

We want to have an 'auth' service, using spring security, which:

1. authenticates incoming request,
2. if successful, adds `userid` to http header
3. forwards request (with header) to another service

What is the easiest way to achieve this kind of forwarding using Spring?

Comment: When asking homework questions, show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having to give us a better understanding of your intentions, what you might be doing wrong, and your goal. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Comment: A simple way is to build a reverse proxy application that uses Netflix Zuul to forward requests to another service. But I am not sure if Zuul could be integrated with Spring Security, or you have to implement a filter by yourself.

Comment: Please try to solve it first and ask if you get stuck in your solution with code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

For this use case, we can create a new Spring Boot application (majorly know as API Gateway) that enables Zuul proxy ([EnableZuulProxy](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy)). Create a custom Zuul `PRE_TYPE` filter that parses all the incoming requests. Its objective would be to check if an incoming request contains token, then call Authentication Service, retrieve the caller's information and add the user's identifier in the custom header.

Once the incoming request is passed through all the filters, then use [`zuul.routes.*`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html) properties to forward a request to appropriate services.

To call remote service (in this case, Authentication Service) we can use Spring's [RemoteTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.html) class. And, [BearerTokenExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/BearerTokenExtractor.html) class for extracting the token from incoming requests. Here's the sample code to get you started:

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    final RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    final HttpServletRequest request = removeCustomHeaders(requestContext.getRequest());

    requestContext.setRequest(request);

    final Authentication authentication = tokenExtractor.extract(request);

    if (Objects.nonNull(authentication)) {
        try {
            final OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = tokenServices.loadAuthentication(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());

            final Map<String, String> userAuthDetails = (Map<String, String>) oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
            requestContext.addZuulRequestHeader(USERNAME_HEADER, oAuth2Authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
            // Add other required information in headers. 
        }
     catch(final AuthenticationException | RestClientException |OAuth2Exception e){
```